# How to extract value from title of link tag using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have something like this:

```
<ul class="links">

    <li>
        <a title="Link 1 description" href="example.html">Link 1</a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a title="Link 2 description" href="example2.html">Link 2</a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a title="Link 3 description" href="example3.html">Link 3</a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a title="Link 4 description" href="example4.html">Link 4</a>
    </li>

</ul>
```

And want to get something like this:

```
<ul class="links">

    <li>
        <span class="description">Link 1 description</span>
        <a title="Link 1 description" href="example.html">Link 1</a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <span class="description">Link 2 description</span>
        <a title="Link 2 description" href="example2.html">Link 2</a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <span class="description">Link 3 description</span>
        <a title="Link 3 description" href="example3.html">Link 3</a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <span class="description">Link 4 description</span>
        <a title="Link 4 description" href="example4.html">Link 4</a>
    </li>

</ul>
```

I need to extract the value from title of every link and then add this value between span tags with addClass description before the li tag.

Any idea how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So since your other question has an accepted answer, this is all done now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('a').each(function() {
    $('<span class="description">' + $(this).attr('title') + '</span>')
        .insertBefore(this);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The `prepend` method has an overload that uses a callback to return the content for each prepend which seems ideal for this, but the function is just fed with the index and the current html, so you have to create new elements from the html to get the title (or use the index to build a selector that can find the element), create an element and turn that into html code to return it, which is a bit of a stretch:

```
$('ul.links li').prepend(function(index, html){
  return $('<div/>').append($("<span/>").addClass('description').text($(html).attr('title'))).html();
});
```

Simply using the `each` method gets you the reference to the container instead, so that you can get the title from the existing element and prepend each span:

```
$('ul.links li').each(function(){
  $(this).prepend($('<span/>').addClass('description').text($('a', this).attr('title')));
});
```

You could also prepend all the span elements first, then copy the title:

```
$('ul.links li').prepend('<span></span>').each(function(){
  $('span', this).addClass('description').text($('a', this).attr('title'));
});
```

---

#### Edit:

With the new additions to the documentation (initiated by patrick dw), the first example gets simpler and more efficient:

```
$('ul.links li').prepend(function(index, html){
  return $("<span/>").addClass('description').text($(this).attr('title'));
});
```

Comment: The first example won't work at all, because the `html` parameter will reference the content only, so `$(html).find('a')` won't find anything, so `.attr('title')` returns `undefined`, which means you're passing `undefined` to `.text()`, which makes it retrieve the text content of the new `<span>`, which will be an empty string that doesn't have an `.html()` method. The `.prepend()` method *does* give you a reference to the container via `this`, just like `.each()` does. http://jsfiddle.net/LFzNg/2/

Comment: @patrick: I corrected the code by simply removing `find('a')`, so now `attr('title')` returns the title, which means that i am passing a string to `text()`, which makes makes it set the text content of the new `<span>`, which doesn't make it an empty string, but an object that has an `.html()` method. Perhaps the `.prepend()` method does set `this` to reference the container, but I can't use it as I can't find anything about it in the documentation, which means that it can change with any new version. http://api.jquery.com/prepend/

Comment: Valid point on `this`. Indeed it isn't there, but I'm guessing it's a documentation bug. The `.attr()` method docs allow it explicitly, while the `.addClass()` docs show it, but only in an example. Still, until it's there, it isn't there. Anyway, you need to remove the `.html()` call, since it is now returning the *content* of the new `span` element, and not the element itself. And all of your examples need to add the `'description'` class.

Comment: @patrick: Oh, thanks, I missed the `description` class. I had to add an extra container to put the span in, to get the HTML code of it. The documentation specifically states for an HTML string.

Comment: Yep, you're right again. An HTML string is officially required as the return value even though the non-function arg `.prepend()` offers many more options. I [filed a bug report](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10051) on the docs to bring consistency to the *thisArg*. If these (IMO expected) behaviors are meant to be official, they should really be writing their docs as carefully as you seem to read them! :)

Comment: [Bug report](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10053) to make alternate return values for the function argument of DOM manipulation methods official.

Comment: FYI, the two bug reports above have been accepted and resolved. There are now more official return values for those function arguments, and the `this` value is officially the current element in the iteration. Thought you might be interested in knowing.

Comment: @patrick dw: Nice, now I can make a shorter version of the first example. :)

Comment: Indeed, and now my solution is *officially valid!* :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.links > li > a[title]').before( function() {
    return $('<span>', {text:this.getAttribute('title'), 'class':'description'});
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/LFzNg/

This passes a function to the [`before()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/before/) method that returns a new element to be placed before each `<a>` element.

---

In a similar manner, you could borrow `.attr()` as an iterator to have a simple way to get the `title` attribute.

```
$('.links > li > a[title]').attr( 'title', function(i,attr) {
    $('<span>', {text:attr,'class':'description'})
        .insertBefore( this );
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/LFzNg/1/

Because you're returning `undefined` implicitly, the `title` attribute is not updated.

Answer (score 0):

First, you'd get all links within your list:

```
var links = jQuery('.links a');
```

Then, you'd create the new elements in a loop. This means for each link a `span` is created and then inserted into the list elements:

```
// Iterate over all links
links.each(function(){
    // this reference points to current element
    var currentLink = jQuery(this);
    // Create a new span element
    var span = jQuery('<span>');
    // Set attributes and content of the span
    span.addClass('description').text(currentLink.attr('title'));
    // Insert the span just in front of the link
    currentLink.before(span);
});
```

Note that the presented code is much more verbose than necessary – but that should hopefully make it easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('ul.links li').each(function () {
    var $li = $(this),
        title = $li.children('a').attr('title'),
        $span = $('<span/>').addClass('description').text(title);
    $li.prepend($span);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('ul.links li a').each(function() {
   $(this).prepend('<span class="description">' + $(this).attr('title') + '</sapn><br/>')
})
```

Comment: I think he wants `prepend`, with an additional `<br>`. (I didn't downvote)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend), not `.wrapInner()`.

```
$('ul.links > li > a').prepend(function ()
{
    return $('<span/>',
    {
        'class': 'description',
        text: this.title
    }).add($('<br/>'));
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/GNpQz/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("ul > li > a").each(function(){
   $(this).prepend("<span class='description'>"+$(this).attr("title")+"</span><br />");
});
```

Comment: You can just pass a function to `.prepend()` and cut out the extra code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').each(function(i){
    $(this).html('<span class="description">' + $(this).attr('title') + '</span><br/>Link ' + i);
});
```